# Как передать файл с linux на windows?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, windows-server

Подскажите, как передать файл с linux-машины на windows? Какие инструмены для этого задействовать? Гуглю уже день - как будто проблема эта требует какого-то нетривиального решения. Ничего не ясно.

Comment: используйте утилиту Bitvise SSH Client

Comment: Неужели гугл не рассказывает про `samba`?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Мне надо с Linux слать файлы в Windows, а все решения, которые я вижу предполагают запуск каких-то команд именно со стороны windows. Почему так?

Comment: То есть, переформулирую, линукс сервер должен заливать файлы на виндовс машину и инициатором скорее всего является какой то скрипт?

Comment: KoVadim - да, именно так. По крону запускает скрипт и должен кроме всего прочего класть файлы на Windows машину.

Comment: Самый простой способ - на линукс сервере поднять самбу, а  на винде ее подмонтировать. Дальше линукс машина просто будет в папку копировать.

Comment: Исходите из того, какие сервисы, способные принимать файлы, у вас уже подняты на windows-сервере. Если файловый — то через smbclient. Если ftp — то через ftp. Ещё что-то — через ещё что-то.

То есть предлагаю сначала рассмотреть более широкую задачу: «как *вообще* передать файл на этот windows-сервер?» После её решения текущая задача сведётся к тривиальной — установке и настройке на линуксе клиента соответствующего протокола.

Answer (score 4):

FTP, Samba, SSH, RSYNC, SCP, WebDAV, Git... Смотря что вы делаете. Можно монтировать сетевые диски, передавать файлы по сети, использовать FTP/SFTP клиенты. Можно использовать облака.

Для синхронизации файлов при разработке обычно используют [RSYNC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)/SSH.

Если это одна локальная сеть нужно/можно использовать Samba сервер и монтировать директории Linux в Windows как сетевые диски.

Плюс

- Можно поднять FTP сервер на Linux и подключаться через клиента (например FileZilla ), но FTP это небезопасно.
- Можно использовать [WinSCP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP) и подключаться через SSH/SFTP.
- Можно использовать облака, типа Яндекс.Диск/Amazon (но это экзотика для простых задач).
- Можно использовать встроенные в IDE (например в PHP/WebStorm) утилиты
- Если это файлы публичного сервера, можно использовать CURL/Wget

В некоторых SSH-клиентах есть возможность передачи файла через обычный интерфейс.

### Linux to Windows

Как вы понимаете, это не тривиальная задача. Системы аутентификации Linux и Windows разные. Для передачи файлов в Windows, можно например: создать разделяемый (shared) ресурс и использовать  `sambaclient` для передачи файлов, но зачем? Еще раз подумайте над вашей задачей, зачем нужно именно так? Можно создавать туннели, установить FTP/SSH сервер на Windows и т.д., но скорее всего, это совсем не нужно и излишне сложно. Пересмотрите саму идеологию работы в гетерогенных средах. Не пытайтесь воспроизводить windows-опыт в Linux. Удачи.

Comment: Я оч далеко от сетевых технологий, я php-программист) 
Суть в следующем: есть сервер  с Red Hat, есть windows машина, точно пока не знаю - одной ли они сети, предполагаю, что да.

Надо перкидывать файлы с Linux на Windows. Я смотрю все решения, но не понятно - везде предполагается, что инициатором является win машина. Ну вот пример - https://www.networkworld.com/article/3269189/linux/sharing-files-between-linux-and-windows.html  - вызов pscp  идет из консоли windows. А мне надо что бы linux слал файлы, а win принимал.

Comment: из консоли вы выполняете команды на удаленном сервере, для того чтобы получить файл нужно просто поменять местами цель/назначение: **туда** `pscp \your\windows\path\file.txt shs@192.168.0.18:/file/on/server/path`; **оттуда**:  `pscp shs@192.168.0.18:/file/on/server/path/file.txt  \your\windows\path` (это из вашего примера)

Comment: удаленный вы имеете в виду - это windows?

Comment: удаленный - linux. Комбинируйте предложенные решения и всё будет ок. Как вы уже догадались для передачи файлов нужны утилиты/программы и сервер на одной из сторон.

Comment: @Василий Filezilla поддерживает все что нужно -  поставте vsftp на Linux и копируйте-отсылайте через Filezilla на win или наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Если сервера в одной сети: то самое простое что можно придумать, это сделать сетевую папку на win машине и монтировать её в linux c помощью smbclient, например в /mnt/winserver

Затем по крону складывать туда необходимые файлы.

Если сервера в разных сегментах или требуется безопасная передача файлов, то можно на windows поставить ssh сервер,
тогда с linux можно передавать с помощью команды scp

Чтобы не спрашивал пароль при каждой передаче  файлов настрой авторизацию по ключу