# Как скопировать сайт?

Tags: ssh, копирование

У меня есть ftp/ssh доступы на сервер с сайтом. Есть необходимость развернуть сайт локально. Как бы мне по-быстрому скопировать папку с сайтом? Я могу просто через ftp но это долго, есть ли другой способ? Сам работаю на винде.

Comment: В линуксе `scp -r .from. .to.`. А в винде попробуйте :  https://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/12972/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731958/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1190061/178576), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/871259/178576) …